# Generate field if it's missing in Python dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have two nested dataclasses `One` and `Two`. I would like to create default empty values if a field in either of the classes is missing.

After some experimenting I was able to get the missing fields from class `One` that are nested in class `Two` to be created correctly, but I am struggling to figure out to how to generate the fields if `f_four` from class `Two` is missing, see example bellow for more details on wanted behaviour.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class One:
    f_one: Optional[int] = field(default=None) 
    f_two: Optional[str] = field(default=None)

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.f_one: Optional[str] = data.get("f_one", None)
        self.f_two: Optional[str] = data.get("f_two", None)



@dataclass
class Two:
    f_three: str
    f_four: Optional[One]

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.f_three: str = data.get("f_three")
        self.f_four: Optional[One] = One(data.get("f_four"))


data_nested_fields_missing = {'f_three': 'three', 'f_four':{}} # Returns Two(f_three='three', f_four=One(f_one=None, f_two=None)) -> created missing f_one and f_two correctly
data_one_field = {'f_three': 'three', 'f_four':{'f_one': 1}} # Returns Two(f_three='three', f_four=One(f_one=1, f_two=None)) -> created missing f_two correctly
data_key_missing = {'f_three': 'three'} # Throws AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' -> I would like to get f_four=One(f_one=None, f_two=None)) in this case

print(Two(data_nested_fields_missing))
print(Two(data_one_field))
print(Two(data_key_missing))
```

Answer (score 0):

just add a default value for `One(data.get("f_four"))`:

```
@dataclass
class Two:
    f_three: str
    f_four: Optional[One]

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.f_three: str = data.get("f_three")
        self.f_four: Optional[One] = One(data.get("f_four", {}))
```

Then the `data` will never be none

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misconception about how dataclasses work. They are supposed to only hold data. So you don't need the init functions. And to pass the dict to the dataclasses you can use dacite, it will automatically pair the variables from the dataclass with the keys from your dictionary.

To set a default value for the variables in your dataclass you don't need to use field, you can just set the equal to None (Or some other value if needed).

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional
from dacite import from_dict # Import dacite

@dataclass
class One:
    f_one: Optional[int] = None # Set a default value of None
    f_two: Optional[str] = None

@dataclass
class Two:
    f_three: str
    f_four: Optional[One]

data_nested_fields_missing = {'f_three': 'three', 'f_four':{}} # Returns Two(f_three='three', f_four=One(f_one=None, f_two=None)) -> created missing f_one and f_two correctly
data_one_field = {'f_three': 'three', 'f_four':{'f_one': 1}} # Returns Two(f_three='three', f_four=One(f_one=1, f_two=None)) -> created missing f_two correctly
data_key_missing = {'f_three': 'three'} # Throws AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' -> I would like to get f_four=One(f_one=None, f_two=None)) in this case

print(from_dict(data_class=Two, data=data_nested_fields_missing)) # <-- Use from dict to pass a dict to a dataclass
print(from_dict(data_class=Two, data=data_one_field))
print(from_dict(data_class=Two, data=data_key_missing))
```

In order to use dacite run:

```
pip install dacite
```